# Switch harddrive to different computer

Tags: linux, hard-drive, computer-architecture

I have an older amd system with a harddrive that has a fedora install on it. I have a newer intel system with a windows 7 install. Would I be able to put the old drive into the new machine and make the fedora install eventually bootable?

Answer (score 2):

Most Linux distributions are pretty versatile. As long as we aren't talking like Fedora 1 from like 2003, it will probably boot fine anyway. Maybe even if it is that old it will be fine.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I shall try it this afternoon.

Comment: Huh. Fedora was able to boot fine, and so was arch, but ubuntu studio wasn't. It showed the studio logo, but didn't do anything, so after 10 minutes I hit the power button. It then started to show activity, then shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but your Fedora probably needs to install drivers for your new system. 
The other thing that you can (which I recommend) is to install both Fedora and Windows on the same hard drive and use the other drive for storing your data. In this case, you can easily boot Windows and Linux by using a bootloader.